# Fixed Length Records

Tags: python, search, replace, record

I am taking an intro to scripting class using python. I have no programming experience so all I know is what the class has taught which is essentially for and while loops, basic functions, lists/dictionaries and currently regex and file handling.

I am being passed a file P that I have to open. I have to search for a variables F (first name) and L (last name) and then switch the birthday associated to F and L to B (birthday).

Each first name is 16 characters long. Each last name is 16 characters long. Each birthday is 8 characters long. Therefore, each record is exactly 40 characters long.

The code below is what I have so far to get the file into a 2d list. How do I then search the list to find F and L? After finding F and L, how do I switch the birthday to B? Hopefully this all makes sense. Thank you in advance.

```
import re
file = open (P, 'r')
data = file.read()

records = []
while len(data) > 0:
  record = []
  record.append(data[0:16])
  record.append(data[16:32])
  record.append(data[32:40])
  records.append(record)
  data = data[40:]
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the text file you are given?

Comment: It looks like you have a program that does everything you need.  What do you need help with?

Comment: @user1558604 He's looking to `append(B)` to the correct `name([F + L])`

Comment: @CanadianCaleb, but he has a 2D list (`records`), which looks something like `[[F,L,B],[F,L,B]...]`.  At least that is the way I understand it.  If he is looking for `F+L+B`, then that would simply be the 40 characters together.

Comment: @user1558604 Yeah, I'm not quite sure how it's, that's why I've asked for an example.

Comment: @user1558604 You are right on what I have to do. I first created a list that looks like [[F,L,B], [F,L,B]...]. I need to search that list for a specific F and a specific L and change the B that is currently given to a different B.

Comment: If that is the case, why split the last, first, and birthday in the first place. They are together in the file, right?

Comment: Because I need to change the B that is currently in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'll asumen that by "switch the birthday associated to F and L" you mean "get the birthday for F and L"

You have created a list of list in the form:

```
[
 [F1, L1, B1],
 [F2, L2, B2],
 [F3, L3, B3],
 [F4, L4, B4]
]
```

You must loop through the first list, and compare the first and second element of the records to match your desire F and L:

```py
for r in records:
  if r[0] == F and r[1] == L:  # List indices starts from 0
    return r[2]
```

You can't `return` if you are not inside a function, so `break` when needed.

Comment: This is very helpful. But I have to switch the B currently in the file to a different B.

Comment: then you can `r[2]  = new_value; return`

Answer (score 0):

@Dustin this should help you in the challenge you are completing.

```
name_length = 16
b_length = 8
start = 0
record_count = 0
records = []

# KISS Method - 2nd Attempt - Read in 16, 16, 8 and output to file

for i in range(start, len(data)):
  record = data[start:start + name_length] 
  records.append(record[0:16])
  start += name_length

  record = data[start:start + name_length]
  records.append(record[0:16])
  start += name_length

  record = data[start:start + b_length]
  records.append(record[0:8])
  start += b_length

  record_count += 1

file1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Dustin - for a 2D list - you would need to use the following - which I believe works.

```
# Loads the file at filepath 
# Returns a 2d array with the data
# 
def load2dArrayFromFile(filepath):
  file = open(filepath, 'r')
  data = file.read()
  lines = data.split("\n")
  for i in range(0, len(lines)):
    lines[i] = lines[i].split("|")

  return lines

# Searches the 2d array 'records' for firstname, lastname.
# Returns the index of the record or -1 if no record exists
# 
def findIndex(records, firstname, lastname):
  for i in range(0, len(records)):
    if (records[i][0] == firstname and records[i][1] == lastname):
      return [i]
    return -1

# Sets the birthday of the record at the given index
# Returns: nothing
def setBirthday(records, index, newBirthday):
  if (index >= 0):
    records[index][2] = newBirthday

# Convert the 2d array back into a string
# Return the text of the 2d array
def makeTextFrom2dArray(records):
  for i in range(0, len(records)):
    records[i] = "|".join(records)
  return ("\n".join(records))

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# 
#  Our main code body, where we call our functions.
#  
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

# Load our records from the file into a 2d array
records= load2dArrayFromFile(P)

# Find out which index, if any, has the name we are hunting
indexWeAreHunting= findIndex(records, F, L)

# Set the birthday record to the one we were passed
setBirthday(records, indexWeAreHunting, B)

# Convert the records into a text string
output= makeTextFrom2dArray(records)

# write the text string out to the file
```

Comment: The trick is to look at the incoming data file - if you review the source data, you would see its one line at a time with the "|" delimiter.  So you first have to split by each new line "\n" then split on the "|".  That should get you on your way, perhaps there is a little bug in there, but I believe it is pretty clean.